# CSS does not get applied on website

Tags: html, css

im trying to change the position of different things on my website but the css styling isnt being applied to the site

[image: image showing the problem]

Comment: Provide code samples, not an image.

Comment: open page in incognito (for chrome) or private browsing page and try

Comment: Try to add `px` unit after numeric values. A unit is required for any numeric CSS values other than `0`.

Answer (score 3):

The values for `padding-top` and `font-size` do not work if you are not using the units. Please give the units like `px` or `em` respectively and make sure you check if the integration works.